# Creating object from class returns instance of another class

Tags: php, oop

I have class DatabaseAccess from which I inherit two classes: TeamAccess and StatisticsAccess. Now when I create instance of TeamAccess from StatisticsAccess it is of type StatisticsAccess? What is happening here?

Heres the code

```
class StatisticsAccess extends DatabaseAccess {
  public function getMatchesById($matchesid) {
    $teamAccess = new TeamAccess();
    print_r(new TeamAccess);
  }
}

class TeamAccess extends DatabaseAccess {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

print_r shows StatisticsAccess object.

Comment: Can't repro this, it works as expected http://3v4l.org/pEYTn

Comment: We are definitely missing some friend - http://codepad.org/Y4ZVyeCe

Comment: Could the problem be that DatabaseAccess creates another instance for PDO and somehow that makes it to convert TeamAccess object to StatisticsObject?

Answer (score 0):

Creating the TeamAccess class inside StatisticAccess will just create a TeamAccess class, just like if you did it outside of a class.

```
class StatisticsAccess extends DatabaseAccess {
    public function test() {
        $teamAccess = new TeamAccess();
        //print_r(new TeamAccess);
        echo "teamAccess var class: " . get_class($teamAccess);
        echo "<br/>this class: " . get_class($this);
    }
}

$sa = new StatisticsAccess;
$sa->test()
?>
```

Returns:

```
//teamAccess var class: TeamAccess
//this class: StatisticsAccess
```

Comment: Sure, I know this and that's why I am asking it here because it isnt.. I tried creating object with same code outside of StatisticsAccess and it works just fine..